# Как вставить HTML код на сайт?

Tags: html, css

Ребят, всем привет.

Как вставить Html код на сайт, как у этого парня в примере:
http://www.kobzarev.com/programming/links-to-icq-and-skype.html

Ниже принтскрин:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто оставлю это здесь

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 2):

Тот парень отвечает: если сайт на WordPress, то рекомендую плагин [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/), именно он у меня раскрашивает код.

Comment: Что не так с моим ответом?

Comment: @DenisBubnov это полноценный ответ на вопрос - топикастер просил именно название плагина, получил развернутый ответ от топикастера (просто развернутее ответить на вопрос "что за плагин" нельзя :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - вставляешь код в какой-нибудь визуальный редактор, после чего смотришь исходник - копируешь его и вставляешь. И тогда у тебя на сайте будет html код отображаться, как текст.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает, записывает в БД нормально, но потом, когда я хочу отредактировать, выгружает уже Html неотредактированный. Вариант Пяткова подходит идеально!